# Flutter Drift/Migration Database issues

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that uses Drift/SQLite database and I made an update on a table ( adding a column ), and I did the migration correctly and tested it and everything went well on my phone ( Xiaomi 11t Android version 13 )

```dart
void _migrationV5(Migrator m) async {
  m.alterTable(
    TableMigration(transactions, columnTransformer: {
      transactions.transactionInDetails: Constant(
        json.encode([]),
      ),
    }, newColumns: [
      transactions.transactionInDetails,
    ]),
  );
}
```

I published the update to find many phones crashing due to the new column not existing!

So I fixed this by upgrading the database version again and did the following ( fixed the creating/updating ...etc ) but still I don't know why the AlterTable didn't work

```dart
void _migrationV6(m) {
  m.addColumn(transactions, transactions.transactionInDetails);
}
```

now I have another issue that didn't exist before this database upgrade :(

I let users backup their data on my server by getting those data as JSON and saving it.

To install those data again I am using the following function that was working just fine and still on my personal phone, but not on another like ( Huawei P30 pro which I have also )

```dart
Future<Map?> setupBackupDatabase({required String source}) async {
  if (source.isEmpty) {
    return null;
  }

  final Map data = json.decode(source);

  final List<dynamic> transactionsJson = data['transactions'] ?? [];
  final List<Transaction> transactions = transactionsJson
      .map<Transaction>((json) => _database.transactions.map(json))
      .toList();

  final List<dynamic> categoriesJson = data['categories'] ?? [];
  final List<Category> categories = categoriesJson
      .map<Category>((json) => _database.categories.map(json))
      .toList();

  final List<dynamic> walletsJson = data['wallets'] ?? [];
  final List<Wallet> wallets =
      walletsJson.map<Wallet>((json) => _database.wallets.map(json)).toList();

  await _database.batch(
    (batch) {
      batch.insertAllOnConflictUpdate(_database.transactions, transactions);
      batch.insertAllOnConflictUpdate(_database.categories, categories);
      batch.insertAllOnConflictUpdate(_database.wallets, wallets);
    },
  );

  return data;
}
```

The error I get is the following ( from using insertAllOnConflictUpdate )

```bash
I/flutter (30607): Drift: Sent BEGIN TRANSACTION with args []
I/flutter (30607): Drift: Executing BatchedStatements([INSERT INTO "transactions" ("id", "value", "transaction_in_details", "date", "category_id", "wallet_id", "priority", "synced") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT("id") DO UPDATE SET "id" = ?, "value" = ?, "transaction_in_details" = ?, "date" = ?, "categor
I/flutter (30607): y_id" = ?, "wallet_id" = ?, "priority" = ?, "synced" = ?, INSERT INTO "categories" ("id", "name", "logo", "type", "priority", "c_order") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT("id") DO UPDATE SET "id" = ?, "name" = ?, "logo" = ?, "type" = ?, "priority" = ?, "c_order" = ?, INSERT INTO "categories" ("i
I/flutter (30607): d", "parent", "name", "logo", "type", "priority", "c_order") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT("id") DO UPDATE SET "id" = ?, "parent" = ?, "name" = ?, "logo" = ?, "type" = ?, "priority" = ?, "c_order" = ?, INSERT INTO "categories" ("id", "name", "logo", "type", "c_order") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,
I/flutter (30607): ?) ON CONFLICT("id") DO UPDATE SET "id" = ?, "name" = ?, "logo" = ?, "type" = ?, "c_order" = ?, INSERT INTO "wallets" ("id", "value", "name", "does_it_has_expire_date", "money_source", "is_active") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT("id") DO UPDATE SET "id" = ?, "value" = ?, "name" = ?, "does_it_
I/flutter (30607): has_expire_date" = ?, "money_source" = ?, "is_active" = ?], [ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(0, [857a4d80-66db-11ee-bcd2-8fa640af0e00, 125.0, [], 1696880351, 52, 021b91dc-d24a-4ea4-8794-5ab6c822c682, 0, 1, 857a4d80-66db-11ee-bcd2-8fa640af0e00, 125.0, [], 1696880351, 52, 021b91dc-d24a-4ea4-8794-5ab6c822
I/flutter (30607): c682, 0, 1]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(0, [8c2e4e60-66db-11ee-bcd2-8fa640af0e00, 580.0, [], 1696880363, 18, 021b91dc-d24a-4ea4-8794-5ab6c822c682, 0, 1, 8c2e4e60-66db-11ee-bcd2-8fa640af0e00, 580.0, [], 1696880363, 18, 021b91dc-d24a-4ea4-8794-5ab6c822c682, 0, 1]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [
I/flutter (30607): 1, تحويل اموال, assets/images/categories/002-currency-exchange.svg, 1, 0, 0, 1, تحويل اموال, assets/images/categories/002-currency-exchange.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [2, الغداء, assets/images/categories/003-spoon-and-fork-crossed.svg, 1, 0, 0, 2, الغداء, assets/images/categorie
I/flutter (30607): s/003-spoon-and-fork-crossed.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [3, 2, المقاهي, assets/images/categories/004-coffee.svg, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, المقاهي, assets/images/categories/004-coffee.svg, 1, 2, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [4, 2, المطاعم, assets/images/categories/003-spoon-and-for
I/flutter (30607): k-crossed.svg, 1, 0, 0, 4, 2, المطاعم, assets/images/categories/003-spoon-and-fork-crossed.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [5, المواصلات, assets/images/categories/005-bus.svg, 1, 0, 0, 5, المواصلات, assets/images/categories/005-bus.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [6,
I/flutter (30607): 5, الوقود, assets/images/categories/006-gas-station.svg, 1, 0, 0, 6, 5, الوقود, assets/images/categories/006-gas-station.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [7, 5, الصيانة, assets/images/categories/007-maintenance.svg, 1, 0, 0, 7, 5, الصيانة, assets/images/categories/007-maintenance.svg,
I/flutter (30607):  1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [8, 5, الجراج, assets/images/categories/008-parking-sign.svg, 1, 0, 0, 8, 5, الجراج, assets/images/categories/008-parking-sign.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [9, 5, الأجرة, assets/images/categories/005-bus.svg, 1, 0, 0, 9, 5, الأجرة, asset
I/flutter (30607): s/images/categories/005-bus.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [10, فواتير, assets/images/categories/010-invoice.svg, 1, 0, 0, 10, فواتير, assets/images/categories/010-invoice.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [11, 10, الكهرباء, assets/images/categories/011-rounded-plug.sv
I/flutter (30607): g, 1, 0, 0, 11, 10, الكهرباء, assets/images/categories/011-rounded-plug.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [12, 10, الغاز, assets/images/categories/flame.svg, 1, 0, 0, 12, 10, الغاز, assets/images/categories/flame.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [13, 10, الأنترنت, assets
I/flutter (30607): /images/categories/012-global.svg, 1, 0, 0, 13, 10, الأنترنت, assets/images/categories/012-global.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [14, 10, الأتصالات, assets/images/categories/013-smartphone.svg, 1, 0, 0, 14, 10, الأتصالات, assets/images/categories/013-smartphone.svg, 1, 0, 0]), Argum
I/flutter (30607): entsForBatchedStatement(2, [15, 10, الأيجار, assets/images/categories/014-rent-hanging-signal.svg, 1, 0, 0, 15, 10, الأيجار, assets/images/categories/014-rent-hanging-signal.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [16, 10, التلفاز, assets/images/categories/015-television.svg, 1, 0, 0, 16, 10
I/flutter (30607): , التلفاز, assets/images/categories/015-television.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [17, 10, المياه, assets/images/categories/016-drop.svg, 1, 0, 0, 17, 10, المياه, assets/images/categories/016-drop.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [18, الأسرة, assets/images/categories/
I/flutter (30607): 017-family-silhouette.svg, 1, 0, 0, 18, الأسرة, assets/images/categories/017-family-silhouette.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [19, 18, الأطفال, assets/images/categories/018-happy-children.svg, 1, 0, 0, 19, 18, الأطفال, assets/images/categories/018-happy-children.svg, 1, 0, 0]), Argu
I/flutter (30607): mentsForBatchedStatement(2, [20, 18, الصيانة المنزلية, assets/images/categories/019-settings.svg, 1, 0, 0, 20, 18, الصيانة المنزلية, assets/images/categories/019-settings.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [21, 18, الخدمات, assets/images/categories/019-settings.svg, 1, 0, 0, 21, 18, الخ
I/flutter (30607): دمات, assets/images/categories/019-settings.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [22, 18, الحيوانات الأليفة, assets/images/categories/020-pawprint.svg, 1, 0, 0, 22, 18, الحيوانات الأليفة, assets/images/categories/020-pawprint.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [23, التعليم, a
I/flutter (30607): ssets/images/categories/021-college-graduation.svg, 1, 0, 0, 23, التعليم, assets/images/categories/021-college-graduation.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [24, 23, كتب دراسية, assets/images/categories/022-book-of-black-cover-closed.svg, 1, 0, 0, 24, 23, كتب دراسية, assets/images/categ
I/flutter (30607): ories/022-book-of-black-cover-closed.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [25, 23, الدورات التدريبية, assets/images/categories/023-online-course.svg, 1, 0, 0, 25, 23, الدورات التدريبية, assets/images/categories/023-online-course.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [26, إستثمار
I/flutter (30607): , assets/images/categories/024-investment.svg, 1, 0, 0, 26, إستثمار, assets/images/categories/024-investment.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [27, الترفيه, assets/images/categories/025-theater.svg, 1, 2, 0, 27, الترفيه, assets/images/categories/025-theater.svg, 1, 2, 0]), ArgumentsFor
I/flutter (30607): BatchedStatement(2, [28, 27, الألعاب, assets/images/categories/026-games.svg, 1, 2, 0, 28, 27, الألعاب, assets/images/categories/026-games.svg, 1, 2, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [29, 27, افلام وصوتيات, assets/images/categories/027-film.svg, 1, 2, 0, 29, 27, افلام وصوتيات, assets/images/cate
I/flutter (30607): gories/027-film.svg, 1, 2, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [30, الرسوم والأشتراكات, assets/images/categories/001-coin.svg, 1, 0, 0, 30, الرسوم والأشتراكات, assets/images/categories/001-coin.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [31, التبرعات والهدايا, assets/images/categories/029-char
I/flutter (30607): ity.svg, 1, 0, 0, 31, التبرعات والهدايا, assets/images/categories/029-charity.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [32, 31, الصدقة, assets/images/categories/028-heart.svg, 1, 0, 0, 32, 31, الصدقة, assets/images/categories/028-heart.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [33, 31,
I/flutter (30607): الزكاة, assets/images/categories/028-heart.svg, 1, 0, 0, 33, 31, الزكاة, assets/images/categories/028-heart.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [34, 31, الهدايا, assets/images/categories/030-giftbox.svg, 1, 0, 0, 34, 31, الهدايا, assets/images/categories/030-giftbox.svg, 1, 0, 0]), Argum
I/flutter (30607): entsForBatchedStatement(1, [35, الصحة واللياقة البدنية, assets/images/categories/031-cardiogram.svg, 1, 0, 0, 35, الصحة واللياقة البدنية, assets/images/categories/031-cardiogram.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [36, 35, الأطباء, assets/images/categories/031-cardiogram.svg, 1, 0, 0, 36
I/flutter (30607): , 35, الأطباء, assets/images/categories/031-cardiogram.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [37, 35, الأدوية, assets/images/categories/034-drugs.svg, 1, 0, 0, 37, 35, الأدوية, assets/images/categories/034-drugs.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [38, 35, العناية الشخصية, asse
I/flutter (30607): ts/images/categories/028-heart.svg, 1, 0, 0, 38, 35, العناية الشخصية, assets/images/categories/028-heart.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [39, 35, الأنشطة الرياضية, assets/images/categories/036-dumbbell.svg, 1, 0, 0, 39, 35, الأنشطة الرياضية, assets/images/categories/036-dumbbell.svg,
I/flutter (30607):  1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [40, التأمينات, assets/images/categories/037-insurance.svg, 1, 0, 0, 40, التأمينات, assets/images/categories/037-insurance.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [41, التسوق, assets/images/categories/038-shopping-bag.svg, 1, 1, 0, 41, التسوق, asse
I/flutter (30607): ts/images/categories/038-shopping-bag.svg, 1, 1, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [42, 41, اكسسوارات, assets/images/categories/032-necklace.svg, 1, 1, 0, 42, 41, اكسسوارات, assets/images/categories/032-necklace.svg, 1, 1, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [43, 41, ملابس, assets/images/categor
I/flutter (30607): ies/033-casual-t-shirt.svg, 1, 1, 0, 43, 41, ملابس, assets/images/categories/033-casual-t-shirt.svg, 1, 1, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(2, [44, 41, الكترونيات, assets/images/categories/039-electronics.svg, 1, 1, 0, 44, 41, الكترونيات, assets/images/categories/039-electronics.svg, 1, 1, 0]), Arg
I/flutter (30607): umentsForBatchedStatement(2, [45, 41, أحذية, assets/images/categories/040-sport-shoe.svg, 1, 1, 0, 45, 41, أحذية, assets/images/categories/040-sport-shoe.svg, 1, 1, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [46, السفر, assets/images/categories/041-airplane-around-earth.svg, 1, 0, 0, 46, السفر, assets/ima
I/flutter (30607): ges/categories/041-airplane-around-earth.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [47, السحب النقدي, assets/images/categories/042-withdrawal.svg, 1, 0, 0, 47, السحب النقدي, assets/images/categories/042-withdrawal.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(1, [48, أخري, assets/images/categor
I/flutter (30607): ies/043-file.svg, 1, 0, 0, 48, أخري, assets/images/categories/043-file.svg, 1, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(3, [49, الراتب, assets/images/categories/001-coin.svg, 0, 0, 49, الراتب, assets/images/categories/001-coin.svg, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(3, [50, المكافآت, assets/images/cat
I/flutter (30607): egories/028-heart.svg, 0, 0, 50, المكافآت, assets/images/categories/028-heart.svg, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(3, [51, الهدايا, assets/images/categories/030-giftbox.svg, 0, 0, 51, الهدايا, assets/images/categories/030-giftbox.svg, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(3, [52, المبيعات, asset
I/flutter (30607): s/images/categories/024-investment.svg, 0, 0, 52, المبيعات, assets/images/categories/024-investment.svg, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(3, [53, الأضافي, assets/images/categories/001-coin.svg, 0, 0, 53, الأضافي, assets/images/categories/001-coin.svg, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(3, [54,
I/flutter (30607):  اخري, assets/images/categories/043-file.svg, 0, 0, 54, اخري, assets/images/categories/043-file.svg, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(3, [5119, ايداع نقدي, assets/images/categories/001-coin.svg, 0, 0, 5119, ايداع نقدي, assets/images/categories/001-coin.svg, 0, 0]), ArgumentsForBatchedStatement(4
I/flutter (30607): , [021b91dc-d24a-4ea4-8794-5ab6c822c682, 125000.0, مصاريف البيت , 0, 1, 0, 021b91dc-d24a-4ea4-8794-5ab6c822c682, 125000.0, مصاريف البيت , 0, 1, 0])]) in a batch
E/SQLiteLog(30607): (1) near "ON": syntax error
I/flutter (30607): Drift: Sent ROLLBACK TRANSACTION with args []
I/flutter (30607): DatabaseException(near "ON": syntax error (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO "transactions" ("id", "value", "transaction_in_details", "date", "category_id", "wallet_id", "priority", "synced") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT("id") DO UPDATE SET "id" = ?, "value" = ?, "transaction_in_details" = ?, "date" = ?, "category_id" = ?, "wallet_id" = ?, "priority" = ?, "synced" = ?, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)) sql 'INSERT INTO "transactions" ("id", "value", "transaction_in_details", "date", "category_id", "wallet_id", "priority", "synced") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT("id") DO UPDATE SET "id" = ?, "value" = ?, "transaction_in_details" = ?, "date" = ?, "category_id" = ?, "wallet_id" = ?, "priority" = ?, "synced" = ?' args [857a4d80-66db-11ee-bcd2-8fa640af0e00, 125.0, [], 1696880351, 52, 021b91dc-d24a-4ea4-8794-5ab6c822c682, 0, 1, 857a4d80-66db-11ee-bcd2-8fa640af0e00, 125.0, [], 1696880351, 52, 021b91dc-d24a-4ea4-8794-5ab6c822c682, 0, 1] #0      wrapDatab
I/flutter (30607): ----------------FIREBASE CRASHLYTICS----------------
I/flutter (30607): DatabaseException(near "ON": syntax error (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO "transactions" ("id", "value", "transaction_in_details", "date", "category_id", "wallet_id", "priority", "synced") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT("id") DO UPDATE SET "id" = ?, "value" = ?, "transaction_in_details" = ?, "date" = ?, "category_id" = ?, "wallet_id" = ?, "priority" = ?, "synced" = ?, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)) sql 'INSERT INTO "transactions" ("id", "value", "transaction_in_details", "date", "category_id", "wallet_id", "priority", "synced") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT("id") DO UPDATE SET "id" = ?, "value" = ?, "transaction_in_details" = ?, "date" = ?, "category_id" = ?, "wallet_id" = ?, "priority" = ?, "synced" = ?' args [857a4d80-66db-11ee-bcd2-8fa640af0e00, 125.0, [], 1696880351, 52, 021b91dc-d24a-4ea4-8794-5ab6c822c682, 0, 1, 857a4d80-66db-11ee-bcd2-8fa640af0e00, 125.0, [], 1696880351, 52, 021b91dc-d24a-4ea4-8794-5ab6c822c682, 0, 1]
I/flutter (30607):
I/flutter (30607): #0      wrapDatabaseException
exception_impl.dart:11
I/flutter (30607): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (30607): #1      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnApplyBatch.<anonymous closure>
database_mixin.dart:699
I/flutter (30607): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (30607): #2      BasicLock.synchronized
basic_lock.dart:33
I/flutter (30607): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (30607): #3      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized
database_mixin.dart:490
I/flutter (30607): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (30607): #4      _SqfliteDelegate.runBatched
drift_sqflite.dart:77
I/flutter (30607): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (30607): #5      Batch._commit
batch.dart:199
I/flutter (30607): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (30607): #6      DatabaseRepository.setupBackupDatabase
database_repository.dart:86
I/flutter (30607): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (30607): #7      SettingsService.setupBackup
settings_service.dart:241
I/flutter (30607): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (30607): #8      BackupCubit.install
I/flutter (30607): ----------------------------------------------------
```